# A @track decorator can only be applied to a public field

Tags: lightning-web-components, track

I'm getting the following error from Salesforce whenever I try to create a Lightning Web Component app:

> Action.prototype.finishAction Error  [Error in $A.getCallback()
>   [Assert Violation: Compiler Error: A @track decorator can only be
>   applied to a public field.] Callback failed:
>   serviceComponent://flexipage.editor.aura.component.FlexipageComponentController/ACTION$loadComponentDefinitions]
>   new
>   Aura.externalLibraries()@https://rlscn--rules.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/pxtF0ZdGYF-z00XsmRUcGQ/aura_proddebug.js:25795:23
>   {anonymous}()@https://rlscn--rules.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/pxtF0ZdGYF-z00XsmRUcGQ/aura_proddebug.js:20710:1

Basically, if I don't use the @track decorator, the error doesn't show. However, using them would be important in my implementation as there are certain values that need to be reflected on my interface. I need these in my app, but my app quite simply won't let me use them. My question is, why exactly is this happening and what can I do to get past this issue?

Comment: hi, please share the component code - otherwise it is difficult to support you

Comment: I wasn't sure if it would've been smart to put all the code here, but here it is through Codeshare. Just to reiterate here, I don't expect an edit (as I know some would probably alter on the page itself), I just need to know why this is happening and how to solve it.

https://codeshare.io/G6ndwz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of your tracked properties have redundant getters (e. g. regionOptions or shippingSpeedOptions etc.). When you are decorating properties you should not add additional getter / setter for them - that is not allowed.
Check your whole Class, remove getter / setter for everything where you are using the @track decorator and then the error should be gone.